# How do I query how many items have changed the status between datetime?

Tags: sql, postgresql, count, window-functions, gaps-and-islands

I have a history table like this

```
id, name, is_active, mod_date
1, 'name1', 0, 2020-06-09 21:00:00
1, 'name1', 1, 2020-06-09 22:00:00
2, 'name2', 1, 2020-06-09 20:00:00
2, 'name2', 0, 2020-06-09 20:10:00
2, 'name3', 1, 2020-06-09 20:20:00
3, 'name4', 0, 2020-06-09 20:00:00
```

The table above is the example of the data. It means `id1` changed the status from 0 to 1 and `id2` change the status from 1 to 0 at the mod_date and later change the name to `name3` as well as flip the `is_active` back to 1. However, `id3` is only a name change to `name4`

I would like to query how many items have change is_active columns. So the answer would be

```
id1, 1
id2, 2
```

`id1` change the is_active column 1 time and `ids2` twice.

Is this even possible in SQL? I'm starting with something like this but I'm not sure how to tell SQL to compare the previous row.

```
select c.id, c.is_active, c.mod_date
from customer_h c
where c.mod_date between '2020-06-09' and '2020-06-10'
order by c.ad_id, c.mod_date
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want keep track of the number of times that the value of `is_active` changes for each `id`. You can use window functions and aggregation:

```
select id, count(*) cnt_is_active_changes
from (
    select 
        h.*, 
        lag(is_active) over(partition by id order by mod_date) lag_is_active
    from history h
) h
where is_active <> lag_is_active
group by id
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=776caa2d5aec059424ec10afe8bf32f9)**:

```
id | cnt_is_active_changes
-: | --------------------:
 1 |                     1
 2 |                     2
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `LAG()` window function to get the previous state and aggregate:

```
select id, sum(changed) counter
from (
  select id, 
    abs(is_active - lag(is_active) over (partition by id order by mod_date)) changed
  from customer_h 
) t
group by id
having sum(changed) > 0
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/26GSTrdNdgRoX9Bm3AegzG/1).
Results:

```
| id  | counter |
| --- | ------- |
| 1   | 1       |
| 2   | 2       |
```